# Historical background of elliptic surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces

I've started learning about elliptic surfaces, primarily through Miranda's *Basic Theory of Elliptic Surfaces* and Schütt & Shioda's *Elliptic Surfaces*.

Although they are useful introductions, they don't give us any sort of historical background and I couldn't find it anywhere.

Does anyone recommend a reference?

Comment: I would expect that these surveys have references to Kodaira's papers on the subject (IIRC he classified the possible singular fibers?). I would hope that these contain at least some discussion of the story up to the 50s.